# how to align horizontal text with radio button and checkbox in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align text with radio button and check boxes. I am using bootstrap for setting the page layout.
Please my markup and correct my code. I have added the snippet for further detail. i need all radio buttons aligned horizontally with text.

```css
input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] {
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #edf8f7;
    /* background-image: none; */
    border: 1px solid #8dc6cd;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio] {
    margin: 4px 0 0;
    margin-top: 1px\9;
    line-height: normal;
}

input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio] {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
}

button, input, select, textarea {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
}

input {
    line-height: normal;
}

button, input, optgroup, select, textarea {
    margin: 0;
    font: inherit;
    color: inherit;
}

* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type="radio" i] {
    margin: 3px 3px 0px 5px;
}

input[type="radio" i] {
    -webkit-appearance: radio;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type="radio" i], input[type="checkbox" i] {
    background-color: initial;
    margin: 3px 0.5ex;
    padding: initial;
    border: initial;
}

input {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    user-select: text;
    cursor: auto;
    padding: 1px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-color: initial;
    border-image: initial;
}

input, textarea, select, button {
    text-rendering: auto;
    color: initial;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: start;
    margin: 0em;
    font: 13.3333px Arial;
}

input, textarea, select, button, meter, progress {
    -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
}
label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    /* font-weight: bold; */
    color: #6b7b8a;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
body {
    background: #fff;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #54667a;
    line-height: 22px;
}

body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<section id="listing">
    
            
                                             
                 <form  id="frmR" action="#" method="post">                                                                                    
                     <h4> Type</h4>
                 <div class="row">     
                     <div class="col-xs-12" >                         
                             <div class="col-xs-4">
                                 <div >
                                     <label class=""> Type</label>
                                     <label ><input type="radio" name="Type" checked="" value="Walk-In">Walk-In</label>
                                     <label ><input type="radio" name="Type" value="Telephonic">Telephonic</label>
                                 </div>
                     </div> 
                 </div>                 
                </form>                                         
                
            
    
</section>
                   
                 
          

     
        <hr />
        <section id="bottom">
   
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`vertical-align`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp) property which sets vertical alignment of an element. Below is the code for your problem

```css
input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] {
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #edf8f7;
    /* background-image: none; */
    border: 1px solid #8dc6cd;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio] {
    margin: 4px 0 0;
    margin-top: 1px\9;
    line-height: normal;
}

input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio] {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
}

button, input, select, textarea {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
}

input {
    line-height: normal;
}

button, input, optgroup, select, textarea {
    margin: 0;
    font: inherit;
    color: inherit;
}

* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type="radio" i] {
    margin: 3px 3px 0px 5px;
}

input[type="radio" i] {
    -webkit-appearance: radio;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type="radio" i], input[type="checkbox" i] {
    background-color: initial;
    margin: 3px 0.5ex;
    padding: initial;
    border: initial;
}

input {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    user-select: text;
    cursor: auto;
    padding: 1px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-color: initial;
    border-image: initial;
}

input, textarea, select, button {
    text-rendering: auto;
    color: initial;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: start;
    margin: 0em;
    font: 13.3333px Arial;
}

input, textarea, select, button, meter, progress {
    -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
}
label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    /* font-weight: bold; */
    color: #6b7b8a;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
body {
    background: #fff;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #54667a;
    line-height: 22px;
}

body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
}
label>input[type="radio"]{
  vertical-align: -30%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<section id="listing">
    
            
                                             
                 <form  id="frmR" action="#" method="post">                                                                                    
                     <h4> Type</h4>
                 <div class="row">     
                     <div class="col-xs-12" >                         
                             <div class="col-xs-4">
                                 <div >
                                     <label class=""> Type</label>
                                     <label ><input type="radio" name="Type" checked="" value="Walk-In">Walk-In</label>
                                     <label ><input type="radio" name="Type" value="Telephonic">Telephonic</label>
                                 </div>
                     </div> 
                 </div>                 
                </form>                                         
                
            
    
</section>
                   
                 
          

     
        <hr />
        <section id="bottom">
   
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```